# Python Pandas - Segmentation Fault after renaming columns?

Tags: python, function, pandas

So after I create a dataframe in pandas, I have a function that capitalizes the headers. But when I try to access the dataframe information after capitalizing, I get a segmentation fault error. If I try to access it before applying the function, I don't have any problems. What could I be doing wrong?

```
reader = pd.read_csv(inFile)

def capitalize_headers(df):
    for i in range(len(list(df.columns.values))):
        df.columns.values[i] = (df.columns.values[i]).upper()

capitalize_headers(reader)

print reader['ColumnName']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you uppercase all of the column names then accessing a column that has lowercase characters will throw an error.

Specifically, the line

```
df.columns.values[i] = (df.columns.values[i]).upper()
```

converts `'columnname'` to `'COLUMNNAME'`. Column access in Pandas is case sensitive, so you would now access that column with `df['COLUMNNAME']`.

Also, here is a more efficient/pythonic way of doing this using [Pandas `str` methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary).

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.capitalize()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I worded that poorly though, I'm sorry. I did try checking ['COLUMNNAME'] and that gives me the same error. Except actually since I've posted this and been working on it my errors have switched to KeyError: 'COLUMNNAME'

Comment: I get segmentation fault though still if I try to print the dataframe

Comment: Actually, okay once I implemented your capitalization function everything worked! I did have to change it though to df.columns.to_series().capitalize() to get it to work. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @MrDinkleburg If this solved the problem, please accept the answer. This allows people to find only open questions.